# Scatter Plot in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot

I have one column that contains my x data and two columns that contain my y data.  I would like to plot y against x, but the length of each column is dependent on a counter variable, i.  I do not have experience with vba, but do with coding.  Can someone outline the correct syntax to perform this task?

Please and Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you need VBA to do this. Just make the scatter plot X and Y ranges longer than you ever expect the data to be. It should just ignore the empty rows.

Comment: @RickTeachey. Excel **will** ignore empty rows in that case **even if** you tell excel to **not** ignore them. (Since the empty rows will always be at the end of the column)

Comment: Use the built in `Table` feature, and that will increase the data range automatically.

Comment: @guitarthrower A big disadvantage of the `Table` feature is it breaks links to external data sources. This is often not an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: @ Rick Teachey: It may not be a trade off in the case of the OP. Since no information is given by the OP, I've offered the option. Regardless, in my experience, depending on your data source, Excel gives you the option to add the External Data Source to your file as a `Table`. So even if the existing data may not be in that format, one could reconnect the data source in this format if desired.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `Table` maintain its connection to external data, i.e. it can be refreshed or pointed to new data without having to start over (delete the table and make a new one)? If so I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: When created via `Get External Data` the `Table` is linked to the external data and refreshes when the data does. (at least in 2010 and later)

Answer (score 0):

You could goto your 'Developer' tab, and record a macro. While in record mode, create the graph using the data and specifications you desire.

End recording of the macro, and you will then have a template of VBA code (ALT+F11) to work with as a foundation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the best solution is to simply make the X-Y scatter plot ranges longer than you ever expect the data to be (Excel will ignore the blank rows).

But if you want to get fancy, you can populate your scatter plot data with dynamic named ranges that automatically adjust to the length of your data without bothering with VBA:

1. Create a dynamic named range (AKA named formula) representing your X data column.

   Example (assuming column `A`, and data starting at `A1`):

   ```
   =$A$1:INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000),0)-1)
   ```

   Change `$A$1` so that it corresponds to the first row of your data. Change `$A$1000` to a row number that is longer than you ever expect your data to be.

   Call the named formula above "`XColumn`" or something similar. To make a named range, do `Formulas`->`Define Name`.
2. Set the X range of your scatter plot equal to:

   ```
   =Sheet1!XColumn
   ```

   Note that Excel's plotting window will give an error (devoid of any helpful information regarding how to fix the problem!)  if you try to input the named range without the sheet name, even if the named range is scoped to the entire workbook, and even if it's on the same worksheet! -- Annoying, right?
3. Do this for each column and scatter plot range (Y1 = Y1Column, Y2 = Y2Column, etc.).

Note that this will not work correctly if your columnar data contains text, blanks, errors, etc., but the method can be modified to handle these issues.

To test and make sure your dynamic named ranges are being created as expected, in any cell you can enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(XColumn)
```

Then do `Formulas`-->`Evaluate Formula`-->`Evaluate` to make sure the `XColumn` array contains the data you want it to contain.

---

Optional tip: create another named range called `FirstColumn` set to the location of the first column, e.g. `$A:$A`. Make *another* named range called `FirstRow` and set it to the location of the first row, e.g. `$1:$1`. Make *yet another* named range called `MaxRow` and set it to the maximum length you ever expect your data to be, e.g. `$1000:$1000`. Finally:

- Replace all instances of `$A$1` above with:

  `INDEX(FirstRow,0,COLUMN(FirstColumn)+<DATA TABLE COLUMN NUMBER - 1>)`
- Replace all instances of `$A$1000` with:

  `INDEX(MaxRow,0,COLUMN(FirstColumn)+<DATA TABLE COLUMN NUMBER - 1>)`

`<DATA TABLE COLUMN NUMBER - 1>` will be different for each named formula (e.g. `0` for `XColumn`, `1` for `Y1Column`, `2` for `Y2Column`, etc etc).

Now if you ever want to create new data tables and scatter plots in different locations, instead of doing all of the work over again you can just copy and paste your named ranges and **you only have to change one or two things instead of 15**! Additionally, if the data ever gets longer than you expected, you only have to change one thing instead of 3.

Comment: Just use Excel's built-in `Table` feature and the range will increase automatically as well.

Comment: One big problem with using Excel's `Table` feature is it breaks links to external data. Sometimes the `Table` is just not the right tool.

Comment: I agree that it is sometimes not the right tool. But then again, yours might not be either. I'm only offering up as a different (potentially less complicated) option, not to disparage your answer, as I've used your solution many times.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's built-in `Table` functionality is a great way to automatically increase a range-size when new data is added. Simply select your data, then either press `Ctrl + t` or go to `Insert > Table`. Then when you reference your new `Table` from the `Chart` it will increase as your data does.